# Some boys in the class are taller than all the girls

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Identify the correct translation into logical notation of the following assertion.

```
Some boys in the class are taller than all the girls
```

Note: taller $(x, y)$ is true if $x$ is taller than $y$.

1. $(∃x)($boy$(x)→(∀y)($girl$(y)∧$taller$(x,y)))$
2. $(∃x)($boy$(x)∧(∀y)($girl$(y)∧$taller$(x,y)))$
3. $(∃x)($boy$(x)→(∀y)($girl$(y)→$taller$(x,y)))$
4. $(∃x)($boy$(x)∧(∀y)($girl$(y)→$taller$(x,y)))$

---

My attempt :

Let $x$ is a boy and $y$ is a girl.

So , "all taller girls"

$(∀y)($girl$(y)→$taller$(x,y))$

hence,

"Some boys in the class are taller than all the girls."

$(∃x)($boy$(x)∧(∀y)($girl$(y)→$taller$(x,y)))$

---

> Can you explain more formally please ?

Comment: $\exists{x}:[\text{boy}(x)]\wedge[\forall{y}:\text{girl}(y)\implies\text{taller}(x,y)]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really a more formal explanation.   You've translated it correctly.

( Well, except for the line "let x ..."; don't include that.   $x$ isn't "a boy"; $x$ is a token entity in the universe of discussion. )

---

"Some boys are something" is : $(\exists x)({\sf boy}(x)\wedge \ldots)$

That something is: "taller than all girls".  $(\forall y)\big({\sf girl}(y)\to{\sf taller}(x,y)\big)$

Putting it together: $(\exists x)\Big({\sf boy}(x)\wedge (\forall y)\big({\sf girl}(y)\to {\sf taller}(x,y)\big)\Big)$

That is all.

Comment: What does $(∃x)(boy(x)∧(∀y)(girl(y)∧taller(x,y)))$ mean ?

Comment: Not much, @mcjoshi . $(\exists x)(\mathsf{boy}(x)\wedge(\forall y)(\mathsf{girl}(y)\wedge\mathsf{taller}(x,y)))$ sais:  "Someone in the class is a boy and everyone in the class is a girl who is shorter than that boy," which is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: So, we use $\land$ when we mean to say that both predicates should always be true and **$\rightarrow$** when left hand need not be strictly true.

Comment: Roughly.  It's more that if we want to say something like "there is some pea that is in a queue" we use  $\exists x~({\sf P}(x)\wedge {\sf Q}(x))$; which means there is something where both statements are true for it.  While if we want to say something like "everything pea is in a queue" we use $\forall x~({\sf P}(x)\to {\sf Q}(x))$, which means that if anything is a pea, then it is in a queue (and we make no claim at all about the queuing of anything that is not a pea).

Comment: I want more clarity by want generalizing meaning to reason out why option 3 is not correct. **(3)** is not correct because using $∃x$ in antecedent allows such $x$ to not exists.
For example $∃x P(x)→Q(x)$ allows no such $x$ exists, as implication ($→$) is true when $P(x)=0$ and $Q(x)=1$ and $∃x P(x)=0$ means no such $x$ exists. Am I correct with this?

Comment: @ahir  To be clear: in a domain where *nothing* satisfies $\mathsf P$ , but *something* satisfies $\mathsf Q$, then *that* something satisfies the implication and so the existence, $\exists x~(\mathsf P(x)\to\mathsf Q(x))$, holds.

Answer (score 0):

[Explanation of the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc2j5.jpg)

[Continuation of explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgbnR.jpg)

Comment: It would be nice to write out the solution...